# How can I run a command after fabric updates my servers?

Tags: python, fabric

Specifically, after I update several servers, I want to print out how many servers were updated. Any advice?

Comment: Keep an incrementing counter?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to run the fab task(s) via fabs [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html) method. The result of the execute method is a dict with the hosts as keys, which would give you a hint for the number of processed hosts.